# Alternative solutions for Hibernate.Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, audit

i'm planning a historization for my java webapp (spring, hibernate).

By googling I found Hibernate.Envers, which seems to be the perfect solution for me.

Are there any comparable solutions?

Thanks a lot!
Jean

Answer (score 4):

The only alternative I know is the [Hibernate Audit Library](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-audit/) but

- It is more focused on auditing than historization.
- I have no idea of the maturity

I would just go for Envers if using Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at **JaVers**: https://javers.org/

It offers quite similar functionality, but with some different tweaks which make it better in some cases (and worse in others).

Here is a comparison of the two:
https://javers.org/blog/2017/12/javers-vs-envers-comparision.html